# Road blocked by WCF: What should I check when seeing "Service Security Context" errors for Primary Identity?

Tags: wcf, authentication

I'm supporting an older Windows Forms application that makes calls to a WCF web service. Our infrastructure team have recently had to move this onto newer hardware (Win Server 2012) and apply new certificates. Now when I try to retrieve data from the web service I'm getting the following message returned:

> Unable to return a valid ID for Primary Identity of current Service
>   Security Context

The section of code (if this is likely to help at all) it hits is:

```
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<CustomServicesClient, TResult> proxy)
    {
        try
        {
            return proxy(Client); // fails here
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            _client.Abort();
            throw new CustomApplicationException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // rethrow any other exception not defined here
            // You may want to define a custom Exception class to pass information such as failure count, and failure type
            _client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The system is using UserName credentials which are configured as:

```
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

The web service is being hit just fine because when a user first logs in, I can step through the following code after the authentication call to the service succeeds:

```
    UraIdentity identity = Security.CustomAuthenticationManager.GetCustomIdentity(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), ds);
    UraPrincipal.Attach(identity, PrincipalAttachType.WinApplication);
```

I've looked around and there really is a dearth of information available out there, so I'm stumped. What sorts of things should I be looking at to try and resolve this issue?